# Flutter: Esconder/Bloquear teclado virtual, porem que o TextField continue a receber caracteres de teclado externo

Tags: flutter, mobile

Estou com o seguinte problema No TextField do flutter 3.7
Eu estou usando no TextField keyboardType: TextInputType.none Para esconder o teclado [Objetivo] Esconder o teclado Virtual ou bloquea-lo ou qualquer outro meio em que ele simplesmente não apareça na tela, porem que ainda aceite caracteres de teclado externos

[Problema] Ao usar o keyboardType: TextInputType.none, ele não reconhece nenhuma tecla além da BackSpace Eu quero que ele aceite todas as teclas mas que so com o teclado externo, não com o teclado virtual, uma vez que quero que ele fique bloqueado